# Dart flutter non-initalized non nullable instance error problem

Tags: flutter, dart

`[
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MnTw.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBclG.png)

i want solution to this matter.
i have tried using late prefix but it wont executed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Answer (score 1):

```dart
You can initialize the list by this way
List<MyMusic> musics = [];
or accept null
List<MyMusic>? musics;
and then unwrap null like this: music!
```